# DataFrame compares two columns with the corresponding contents respectively and check the consistency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where there are two columns doubtfully holding the same information and want to check their consistency.

In detail, the goal is to see that whether when `is_canceled` is `0` (`1`), then `reservation_status` must be `Check-Out` (`Canceled`), and print the outliers if exists.

```py
df.loc[1:100, ['is_canceled','reservation_status']]
```

shows:

[image]

I tried several methods such as

```py
# Check the outlier
(df['is_canceled'] == 0 and df['reservation_status'] == 'Canceled').any(1)
```

but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it's spelled Cancelled, but assuming you want to use Canceled, you can use `.loc` with your multiple conditions inside of parenthesis and use `&` not `and`, with `|` for `or` separating the two of those.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'is_canceled':[0,0,1,1], 'reservation_status': ['Check-Out','Canceled','Check-Out','Canceled']})

df.loc[
    ((df['is_canceled']==0) & (df['reservation_status']!='Check-Out')) |
    ((df['is_canceled']==1) & (df['reservation_status']!='Canceled'))
]
```

Output

```
    is_canceled reservation_status
1   0                     Canceled
2   1                    Check-Out
```

Comment: Yes, it's weird. For no reason, this published dataset use `canceled` in all the data points